# Cache control and page expired issue

Tags: php, html, header, cache-control

For avoiding, page expired issue while clicking on back button, we have added below code in every pages.

```
header("Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0",false);
session_cache_limiter("must-revalidate");
```

Can someone tell me, what are the possible disadvantages or is there any way to avoid page expire issue?

Comment: But `Last-Modified` will always be the present date ...

Comment: @MihaiIorga yes, but this is fixing the document expired issue...

Comment: You've made the page to Expire in the past. Browser would have to renew it. What web server do you use?

Comment: @webbandit we are using apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using Apache you don't have to use PHP `header()` methods.

With Apache [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.htm) module you can controls the setting of the `Expires` HTTP header and the `max-age` directive of the `Cache-Control` HTTP header in server responses.

For example if you want want all your page to expire `in 1 month` (and not to be reloaded by the browser) use next config lines within your `httpd.conf` file, `<VirtualHost>` section or in `.htaccess` file:

```
ExpiresActive On // Enables "Expires" and "Cache-Control" headers generation
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month" // All resources expire after 1 month
```

Comment: Our goal is not caching but to avoid page expire issue while clicking on back button. This code is fixing that issue but would like to know if there is any drawback of using this code

Comment: No drawbacks, this is the mos preferable way because your php script would run as usual, you would'n have to `exit;` in PHP script after sending headers. Apache would do everything for you.